# How to allow unauthenticated requests to a controller when rest of site is using Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, azure-active-directory

We have a website with a bunch of API controllers. The website is set up to use Azure AD auth as follows:

```
    services
        .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

I need to add some new controller actions (either to an existing controller or an entirely new controller) that do not require authentication because they need to be called by a third party service that does not have the ability to do authentication with `Azure AD`. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Decorate the controller and/or action with `[AllowAnonymous]` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, if we update `Startup.cs` as the following code

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                   .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.AddControllers();
```

And We do not add `[Authorize]` on the Controller. Then we can directly access the api and do not need to do Azure AD Authentication.
[image] 
[image]

Besides, if we want to authenticate one method in the Controller, you just need to add `[Authorize]` on the method
[image]
[image]

---

Update

According to my test, we also can do that in .Net Core 2.2
1. Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, those look like features of .Net Core 3 and this site is only running on 2.2 currently.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung According to my test, we also can do that in .net core 2.2. For more details, please refer to my update

Answer (score -1):

Have not worked with Azure AD but for my API's that use JWT I use the [AllowAnonymous] attribute above the method or the entire controller.
Example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeMethod(string id)
{....
 ....
}
```

Comment: No, AllowAnonymous does not work because the Azure AD authentication prevents the request from even being sent to the controller where it could see that attribute.